# how to theme raised button, flat button separately in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a custom theme in material ui using react.

```
palette: {
primary1Color: pink500,
primary2Color: pink500,
primary3Color: grey300,
accent1Color: grey500,
accent2Color: grey500,
accent3Color: grey300,
textColor: darkBlack,
alternateTextColor: white,
canvasColor: white,
borderColor: grey300,
disabledColor: fade(grey700, point3),
pickerHeaderColor: cyan500,
clockCircleColor: fade(darkBlack, point7),
shadowColor: fullBlack
```

}

The pallet is something like this. The flatbuttons are working fine but raised buttons are taking the accent1Color: grey500, as background. Which I don't want and the same time I don't want to use the props like "labelStyle" and "backgroundColor" to override. Is there any other way to specifically create a theme option where I just have to add secondary={true} and it will take backgroundColor as grey50 and labelStyle as grey900.

Any help will be appreciated. Hoping for some help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create something like this. You can use this method to override what colors each component uses. Note that I have used `primary1Color` everywhere as just an example.

```
const palette = {
  primary1Color: '#ffc20e',
  primary2Color: '#e30413'
}

const theme = {
  palette: palette,
  raisedButton: {
    color: palette.primary1Color,
    textColor: palette.primary1Color,
    primaryColor: palette.primary1Color,
    primaryTextColor: palette.primary1Color,
    secondaryColor: palette.primary1Color,
    secondaryTextColor: palette.primary1Color,
    disabledColor: palette.primary1Color,
    disabledTextColor: palette.primary1Color,
  }
}

<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(theme)}>
    <div className='appContainer'>
       {children}
    </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```